# How can I merge two lists column-wise?

Tags: windows-7

I need to merge two very large lists together.

**File1.txt**

- Washington|
- Ohio|
- Dublin|
- London|
- Milan|

**File2.txt**

- Greg
- Tom
- Paul
- Sharon
- Bill

**Output.txt**

- Washington|Greg
- Ohio|Tom
- Dublin|Paul
- London|Sharon
- Milan|Bill

How can I do that in Windows?

Comment: Pretty much any program that compares two files and allows you to merge the differences can do something like this.

Comment: @Ramhound All the programs like that I have used will let you overwrite one line with another, but I've never run into a program that will append lines together, I could be wrong though, and I always like to learn new things, could you expand your comment into an answer explaining how to do this?

Comment: @Ramhound most merge programs just overwrite the differences rather than appending.

Comment: See: [Merge 2 txt files in a single tab delimited file in batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031687/merge-2-txt-files-in-a-single-tab-delimited-file-in-batch). In Unix, you'd have `paste` for that.

Answer (score 1):

I got a working solution. Pasted the rows to Excel and exported it as text file, rather than an XLS file.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not too much data you should be able to do this with something like MS Office or LibreOffice.  Load the two text files, cut n paste them into different columns in a spreadsheet  (Col A for file 1, col b for file 2) then cut and paste (special, raw text) back into a text doc.

It's not pretty but it will work with some manual work on your part.

Comment: I am afraid its 10K of data :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the `paste` command line utility that comes with my [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm).  If this is a one-time thing, you'll be happy with the [free version](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Demo.htm) of my C shell.  Full disclosure:  I'm the author.

```
paste -d \0 File1.txt File2.txt > Output.txt
```

Here's what it looks like on your data:

```
176 C% cat File1.txt
Washington|
Ohio|
Dublin|
London|
Milan|
177 C% cat File2.txt
Greg
Tom
Paul
Sharon
Bill
178 C% paste -d \0 File1.txt File2.txt
Washington|Greg
Ohio|Tom
Dublin|Paul
London|Sharon
Milan|Bill
```

[Cygwin](http://Cygwin.org) also includes a `paste` but to use that one, you'll need to ensure that all the lines end with only a newline (`\n`) character, Unix-style, not a carriage return-newline (`\r\n`) combination Windows-style or you'll get this:

```
179 C% \cygwin\bin\paste -d \0 File1.txt File2.txt
Gregington|
Tomo|
Paulin|
Sharon|
Billn|
```

(The Cygwin `paste` treats the `\r` as an ordinary character.  On the screen, it moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, overwriting what was there.)

Answer (score 0):

command line, var 1:

```
powershell $f1=gc File1.txt;$f2=gc File2.txt;for($i=0;$i-lt$f1.length;$i++){$f1[$i]+$f2[$i]}>Output.txt
```

command line, var 2:

```
powershell $f1=gc File1.txt;$f2=gc File2.txt;for($i=0;$i-lt$f1.length;++$i){$f1[$i]+$f2[$i]^>^>Output.txt}
```

paste-d.ps1

```
$f1=gc File1.txt;$f2=gc File2.txt;for($i=0;$i-lt$f1.length;++$i){$f1[$i]+$f2[$i]>>Output.txt}
```